# Why does my Dockerfile CMD not work?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile

So at the end of my Dockerfile I have this:

```
WORKDIR /home
CMD django-admin startproject whattt
CMD /bin/bash
```

When I create image and then run container, everything works as expected there are no errors, and no errors in the Docker log.  However there are still some issues that I cannot seem to figure out.

The first and most important problem is that CMD django-admin startproject is not actually creating any project.  AFTER I run the container, then I can manually run django-admin startproject and it works as expected.  When I issue this as a CMD from the Dockerfile though, then no project gets created.

The second issue is after the django-admin line, I put a second CMD with /bin/bash so when I run the container it opens a shell (so I can go in and check if my django project was created).  Will this create a problem or conflict with the previous django-admin line?  If I remove this line, then when I run the container I have no way to open the shell and check if my django project is there do I ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.” via [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). So your first CMD will not take effects.

If you want to execute the bash of your container, try `docker exec` command, and [the document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) provides example commands so you can follow.